# PHP login redirect security?

Tags: php, security, redirect

I wish to redirect users to the login page if they attempt to visit a page which requires them to be logged in. After logging in, however, I want to redirect the user back to their original destination. I've written a "redirect.php" script which is to be included on all such pages:

```
<?php
require "session.php";
if(!$user){
    header("Location: login.php?dest=".urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
    die();
}
?>
```

Then on my login page I have the following:

```
<?php 
$dest = "./";
if(isset($_GET["dest"])){
    $dest = $_GET["dest"];
}
?>
```

with the following javascript:

```
var URL = "<?php echo $dest; ?>";
//...
//upon successful login (via AJAX):
window.location.replace(URL);
```

Everything here works as intended but where does this stand from a security standpoint?

One vulnerability that comes to mind is something like mysite.com/login?dest=http://phishingsite.com. How might I best prevent something like this? Would regex be suitable here?

Are there any other security concerns with this type of thing? Perhaps a standard way of doing this? Or better yet, a method which does not use GET variables at all?

Comment: Post this in Code review or the Security exchange. You'll get a better response. We work with *busted* code. ;)

Comment: Redirect to the default page like index.php?

Comment: That would solve my security issues but isn't a solution for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the redirect uri in the session and let the login page read it from there.
A hacker have no chance to pass the destination through the url nor with a form post.

Comment: I hadn't even considered using sessions prior to the user authenticating themselves. This appears to be an entirely better way of doing this. Why does the GET approach even exist?

Comment: GET is just a method of the HTTP protocol, the programmer should use it with the due care.